# google analytics different domain, different pages

Tags: javascript, web-services, google-analytics, multiple-domains

i have 2 domains:

1. www.example.com
2. www.aboutexample.com

and on nginx, i have set a proxy to do:

```
www.example.com -> server:81
www.aboutexample.com -> SERVER:81/about
```

so,

```
www.aboutexample.com/some/things == www.example.com/about/some/things
```

on my pages i have analytics set like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', ANALYTICS_ID],['_trackPageview']);
```

when you check the main domain

`www.example.com/about/some/things` i get `/about/some/things`

bet when you check the about domain:

`www.aboutexample.com/some/things` i get `/some/things`

i have fixed this by adding 2 analytics accounts, one for the `example.com` and other to `aboutexample.com`, and the server toggles between them depending on the domain, but is there any way to join them in one main(example.com) analytics accounts and add the `aboutexample.com/*` as `example.com/about/*`?

Comment: Note: you use a forward slash (`/`) in an url to separate parts of the path, not a backward slash.

Comment: Goto the admin section for example.com and use a custom filter (search and replace or an advanced filter) to remove the leadung "/about" with request url as filter field.

Comment: if i understand correctly, i actually need the oposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [virtual pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples#VirtualPageviews) to track them on the same url so the reports make sense.

You will still be able to tell one domain from the other from the hostname report but the urls on the Pages report should now look the same.

eg:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', ANALYTICS_ID]);
if(document.location.hostname === 'www.aboutexample.com'){
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/about' + document.location.pathname + document.location.search]);
}else{
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
}
```